# jupyter notebook kernel dies when running a UNet

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I was running my code with `tensorflow=2.0.0` to run a UNet using jupyter notebook. When I upgraded to `tensorflow=2.1.0` my code will note run. Before the first epoch ends I get a message saying `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`. The UNet is using `MirroredStrategy()` to distribute the UNet to the GPUs. I don't get this error when I remove `MirroredStrategy()` and run on a single-gpu. Any idea why `tensorflow=2.1.0` would cause this problem?

```
def get_model(optimizer, loss_metric, metrics, lr=1e-4):
    with tf.device('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0'):
        inputs = Input((sample_width, sample_height, sample_depth, 1))
        conv1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
        conv1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
        pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv1)
        drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)
        conv2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
        conv2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
        pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv2)
        drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)
        conv3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
        conv3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
        pool3 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv3)
        drop3 = Dropout(0.3)(pool3)
        conv4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
        conv4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
        pool4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv4)
        drop4 = Dropout(0.3)(pool4)
        conv5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
        conv5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
    with tf.device('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1'): 
        up6 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(256, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=4)
        conv6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
        conv6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)
        up7 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=4)
        conv7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
        conv7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
        up8 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=4)
        conv8 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
        conv8 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)
        up9 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=4)
        conv9 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
        conv9 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)
        conv10 = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)
        model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr), loss=loss_metric, metrics=metrics)
        return model

smooth = 1.
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    model = get_model(optimizer=Adam, loss_metric=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef], lr=1e-4)
observe_var = 'dice_coef'
strategy = 'max'
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('{epoch:04}model', monitor=observe_var, save_best_only=True)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = 2, epochs= 1000, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=.2, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
model.save( 'finalmodel')
```

Comment: Can you please include a minimal, reproducible example? It will be much easier to help with code.

Comment: added code to help reproduce the issue

Comment: Seems like you are running out of memory. Instead of Jupyter notebook use .py script. It doesn't allow cuda to deallocate resources once the session is over which creates problems. Thanks!